# Was there an [a] sound in PIE?

Tags: proto-indo-european, comparative-method

I have come across a controversy about the [a] vowel sound in PIE. I have noticed in most reconstructed PIE words the [a] sound is not present, even when it seems to be present in most of the daughter languages, and it only seems to be reconstructed for some rare words. I have looked it up and it appears there is a debate among scholars on whether there was an [a] sound or at all. What are the reasons for this?

Also, are there any historically attested examples of [e] and [o] becoming [a] in IE languages?

Answer (score 8):

The evidence for a phonemic *a in earliest PIE (before Anatolian and Tocharian broke off) is extremely lacking, it only seeming to be present in a small number of words that are likely borrowings, often present in only a small number of branches.

That said, a-colouring from *h2 is attested in all branches, and so *a  ought to be reconstructed for earliest PIE, just only as an allophone of *e rather than as a phoneme in its own right.

Late PIE (after Anatolian and Tocharian broke off) seems to have for the most part either lost or merged the laryngeals, meaning this earlier *a allophone had become phonemic.

For your second point, it's worth remembering that in reconstructions, the labels *e, *o, *a (and indeed any other symbols at all that are in use) are purely for convenience and should not be taken too literally as representing the sounds represented by those symbols in the IPA, and their exact realisation is very much open to debate (in particular, there is debate over whether *o was even rounded in most instances).

So, we shouldn't be looking for instances of [e] & [o] becoming [a], but front & back non-high vowels becoming low unrounded vowels.

Spontaneous rounding and unrounding of non-high back vowels (especially lower vowels) is extremely common (as an example in the historic era, look at the American unrounding of the LOT vowel), so *o becoming *a (and vice versa) are completely unsurprising.

Lowering of mid front vowels is also not unusual (as a recent example, the DRESS vowel /ɛ/ in English has become variously [æ] & [ɐ] in California & Northern Cities English respectively). Schwas (another candidate for the sound of PIE *e) are also very frequently lowered. Likewise, non-high front vowels often become non-high back vowels which can then unround for the same reasons mentioned above. As you can see, *e becoming *a also isn't especially odd, even if it is less expected than it is for *o.

From a PoV of looking at the vowel system as a whole, 5-vowel systems are pretty stable, and 3-vowel systems are both pretty stable, but 4-vowel systems are not, so once *o and *a merge, that may provide enough pressure to encourage the *e to merge too (or else for there to be another split, returning back to a 5-vowel system).

Comment: Thank you, that was a brilliant answer and cleared up the matter mostly to me.

Comment: Just a few more questions in relation to what you said. What do you mean by "H2 colouring in all IE languages"? I thought the laryngeal were only found in Anatolian and have been lost everywhere else? Also, I meant attested examples of e's and o's becoming a's. I have looked through many IE families and I have seen a sounds turn into e and o, but not e and o into a. Sometimes it can be in part of word and sometimes  all of it e.g. Tocharian A Macar, Pacar > Macer, Pacer. The "car" becomes "cer"; Sanskrit Ka > Bengali Ke, Punjabi Ker; Sanskrit Sa > Bengali Se, Oriya Se.

Comment: the laryngeals are only found explicitly in Anatolian (with the possible exception of a small number of preservations in other branches), but all branches show h2 colouring an adjacent *e to *a

Comment: and I give you explicit examples of e- & o-type vowels becoming a-type vowels in the answer...

Comment: There are explicit traces of *H2 also in Armenian, Kurdish and some Iranian languages.

Comment: h2 is generally lost in those languages, but yes, those languages do have some of the possible exceptions I mentioned (Albanian is the other commonly cited example)

Comment: Seeing how volatile vowels can be, shifting here and there so irregularly, I am surprised how we can reconstruct PIE vowels at all. Also, could someone explain to me exactly why a 4-vowel system would be unstable?

Comment: "So, we shouldn't be looking for instances of [e] & [o] becoming [a], but front & back non-high vowels becoming low unrounded vowels." - Do you mean this? I think  I get it, but I want to see examples of it in IE language. As I can't seem to see any. Like I have given Macar - Macer; Sa to Se etc. Is there an equivalent, like say Ke to Ka? Please dont mind my question, im still learning and its all new to me.

Comment: @LinguistEnthusiast I give examples of e-like vowels becoming a-like, and of o-like vowels becoming a-like within English in the answer itself. I am unsure why you do not consider these examples

Comment: "3-vowel systems are both pretty stable" - - you mean *bi-stable*? ;-)

Comment: @QuintusCaesius-RM seeing that Ablaut, tone, length, feature prediction and other phenomena are significant for meaning, the vowels might be even more important than consonants, which are only meaningful in morphemic clusters. The difficult part is semi-vowels and other not fully consonant phones like aspiration, glottalization, etc. Vauel-shifts may prove volatilite, but they can be shown to be regular in many instances. Native speakers reproduce vowels with a high degree of precision, so it must be others which may give the impression of randomness in any of the pluralistic world languages.

Comment: Regarding semi-vowels and such like: if for example En. *-er* ~ *-a* /ɚ/ and Ger. *der* "the" /dɛɐ̯/, or *r* /​χ​/ after voiceless Consonants counts for anything, I would be inclined to believe for example that \*h2leg- (cp. ἀλέγω) can derive *religio* < \*H̥leg without any prefix, see also rhotic *warshed* "washed", and the "ermahgerd, mershed perderders" meme. Cf. *"*\a has various origins, among which are a "syllabic" [H̥]"*. Such rhotics would also be an alternative for Hittite word initial *ḫ*, by the way, the issue is *not!* settled.

Comment: @vectory I see, but just taking the example of old English to modern English (though this example might be a terrible one), it is quite difficult to guess the vowel of the ancestor of a word just by hearing it, or even looking at the orthography. I do understand that there are patterns, but it is still feels highly irregular.

Comment: @QuintusCaesius-RM this is largely because Modern English descends from Mercian Old English, but normalised Old English is West Saxon. Combined with the fact that sound changes are not, in general, reversible, of course trying to predict the normalised Old English form from the Modern English is going to be difficult

Comment: I see, was there a huge difference between dialects of old English?

Comment: wikipedia has an overview. They're still fairly close, but the vowels often differ: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_Old_English#Dialects

Answer (score 6):

The general consensus is that, phonetically, early PIE had a low vowel of some sort (which could broadly be called `[a]`), but phonemically, it did not have a phoneme `/a/` (or it had a marginal one at best).

The reason for assuming a phonetic `[a]` is that various words have a consistent low vowel across several daughter languages, like in "before, fore, front" (Latin *ante*, Greek *anti*, Sanskrit *anti*).

The reason for *not* assuming a phonemic `/a/` is that, for the most part, it doesn't seem to be necessary. When we see those consistent low vowels, the laryngeal theory explains them as an underlying `/e/` adjacent to `/h₂/`. And indeed, Hittite shows a direct reflex of `/h₂/` in the "front" word: ***ḫ**ant-* "face, fore". (Reconstructed PIE phonemes are generally written like **this* rather than `/this/`, and that's what I'll use for the rest of the answer.)

Why not assume a phonemic `/a/`? Because this "laryngeal-coloring" theory very nicely explains certain inconsistencies in ablaut (the way the main vowel within a PIE root changes in different forms). For most roots, there are three common ablaut grades: ∅, *e*, and *o*. But certain roots seem to replace the *e*-grade with something else: sometimes *ō*, sometimes *ā*, sometimes *ē*. And these same roots do something weird with the ∅-grade, which varies by language; in Greek, the ∅-grade of those roots show *o*, *a*, and *e*, respectively (Greek *did**ō**mi* "give", *d**o**tos* "given"; *hist**ā**mi* "stand", *st**a**tos* "stood"; *tith**ē**mi* "place", *th**e**tos* "placed"); in Latin, the ∅-grade is always *a* (*d**a**tus* "given", *st**a**tus* "stood", *f**a**ctus* "done").

If we assume laryngeals, these inconsistencies completely disappear. Those roots are now reconstructed as **deh₃*, **steh₂*, **dheh₁*; the weird long vowels are the result of a laryngeal after **e*; the weird short vowels are the result of a laryngeal on its own without a vowel next to it. And the ablaut is back to the classic ∅ vs *e* vs *o*, same as any other root.

And once we've added the laryngeals to the theory, well, it turns out they can explain basically all instances of phonemic **a*. Some linguists still reconstruct **a* as a marginal phoneme in words like **aból* "apple", while others explain even these instances away as **h₂eból*. At this point, adding **a* to the theory as a full-on phoneme makes it more complex without adding much explanatory power, so Occam's razor suggests we should leave it out.

Comment: This was a very detailed explanation. It was very technical for me when you started to about Ablauts and grades. But I sort of get it. Please correct me if I am wrong, the Laryngeal basically replaces the *a phoneme, in order to account for the irregularity of deriving a, e and o from the root PIE vowel as it appears to behave erratically in different form. Is this correct?  Curiously then, before the Laryngeal theory was adopted, how was deh3, steh2 and dheh1 reconstructed?

Comment: @LinguistEnthusiast Before the laryngeal theory caught on, they were reconstructed as irregular roots *dō *stā *dhē which didn't follow normal ablaut patterns.

Comment: A related question to Laryngeals. How do we know they are definitely a feature of PIE, and not just a substratum influence in Antatolian from an Arabic language which are known for Laryngeals right?

Comment: @LinguistEnthusiast I'd recommend asking that as a new question. The short answer is that we see indirect evidence of them in many different branches, even if Anatolian is the only one with direct attestation. (Also, Arabic is much later than the Anatolian languages; you'll want to look at Akkadian, which lost most of its "gutturals".)

Comment: Thanks Dranconis. You have been very helpful. When you say "normal ablaut patterns" do you mean like Latin always preserves the one sound *a in all forms of the word. This is regular?

Comment: @LinguistEnthusiast Also worth asking as its own question. To put it briefly, different constructions use different ablaut grades of the same root. For most roots, those grades are e, o, ∅.

Comment: Also worth asking: Why is the system expected to be highly regular, while any major language proves irregular verbs, which, vranted, can be explained from this system, but certainly not in all cases? Corallary: the problem is not o ly that \*dō \*stā \*dhē wouldn't follow normal ablaut patterns, but that some reflexes would independently require largley irregular changes with no discernable pattern between agreeing and disagreeing branches; notably, *dádāti*, etc. from \*dádaHti < \*dédeh₃ti is regular in Indo-Iranian at least, as is \*bʰāráyati < \*bʰoréyeti, *bʰer- without any one laryngeal.

Answer (score 4):

To your last point: In Indo-Iranian IE *e and *o regularly become “a”, *ē and *ō regularly become “ā”. The only notable exception is that *o in open syllables becomes long “ā”.

For example: Greek hepta = Vedic sapta- = Persian haft. Greek oktō = Vedic aṣṭā = Persian hašt.